# Adding a keyframe to a constraint influence

Tags: python

I have an object with a Limted Rotation Constraint applied to it and would like to keyframe the influence. Here is the script I am using. I have tried `bpy.context.object.constraints[‘Limited Rotation’].keyframe_insert(data_path=“influence”)` at the end. I can't get it to work.. ?

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') #deselect all object

bpy.data.objects['ForwardPath'].select_set(True) 
obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects['ForwardPath'] 
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

to_add = bpy.context.active_object

add_constraint = to_add.constraints.new('LIMIT_ROTATION')

target = bpy.data.objects['ForwardPath']

bpy.ops.object.parent_clear(type='CLEAR')

bpy.context.object.constraints["Limit Rotation"].use_transform_limit = True 
bpy.context.object.constraints["Limit Rotation"].owner_space = 'LOCAL' 
bpy.context.object.constraints["Limit Rotation"].use_limit_x = True 
bpy.context.object.constraints["Limit Rotation"].min_x = 0 
bpy.context.object.constraints["Limit Rotation"].max_x = 6.28319    
bpy.context.object.constraints["Limit Rotation"].influence = 1
```

Comment: Use the reference `add_constraint` eg `add_constraint.influence = 1` and `add_constraint.keyframe_insert(data_path="influence")`  Also please use code markdown for code, not quote.

Comment: batFinger thanks gain,is it possible to contact you for your services? I will delete this comment after.